# Why can't (or won't) C++ deduce alias templates?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, c++-templates

It seems that C++ is either unable or unwilling to infer template arguments for template aliases of basic integer types.

Here is a relatively minimal example:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>


template<typename T>
using IntPtr = intptr_t;

template<typename T>
T* getPtr(IntPtr<T> i)
{
    return (T*) i;
}


int main()
{
    IntPtr<char> char_star = 0xcafe'babe'dead'beef;
    return *getPtr(char_star);
}
```

Attempting to compile the above gives the following error:

```
$ clang -xc++ -std=c++20 why.cc
why.cc:17:13: error: no matching function for call to 'getPtr'
    return *getPtr(char_star);
            ^~~~~~
why.cc:8:4: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
T* getPtr(IntPtr<T> i)
   ^
1 error generated.
```

I've tried with various different C++ standard versions, including c++2b, but the result was always the same.

Comment: What `T` would you expect to be deduced and why? How is that `T` derived from the type of `char_star`? (And what is that type btw?). I think the answer should be obvious if you try to answer these questions.

Comment: Side note btw: `clang -xc++ -std=c++20 why.cc` is wrong to compile a C++ program. It should be `clang++ -std=c++20 why.cc` instead. The first form will not invoke the linker correctly.

Comment: Also `stdint.h` should be `cstdint`

Answer (score 1):

> ```cpp
> template<typename T>
> using IntPtr = intptr_t;
> ```

`T` is not deducible from `intptr_t`, so this cannot possibly work.

`IntPtr<char>` is `intrptr_t`, so you're asking the compiler to deduce `T` from `intrptr_t`, which simply cannot be done. Aliases in C++ are weak aliases, not distinct types.

You could instead write:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T* getPtr(std::intptr_t i)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(i);
}

// ...
getPtr<char>(0xcafe'babe'dead'beef);
```